# Mongo replica set reconfig when primary and majority don't exist

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database-replication

Is there anyway to reconfigure a replica set in the event the primary as well as a majority of the servers are down. For example if data center 1 goes does, a procedure can be run to reconfigure and set a new primary with the remaining servers?

I keep getting this "Command '$eval' failed: not master (response: { "note" : "from execCommand", "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not master" })"

We only have 2 data centers. (If we had 3 then I realize that would solve this problem.)
I was thinking about running a reconfigure on a 5 member replica set every time the fail over happens and changing the host of the arbiter from one data center to another so that the active data center will always have the arbiter, but I can't do that if 3 of the 5 members of the replica set aren't available...because not new primary will ever be set.

As a side note, I'm trying to do this in a .NET web service using the MongoDatabase.Eval() method of the mongo .NET driver, but even when I pass in a simple javascript method, I get an exception saying it failed because it's not the master. Is there another method I can use besides eval that doesn't require it to be executed on primary?

I'm fairly new mongo so if you have any suggestions, I'm all ears!

Comment: Are your data centers going offline enough to make this something you want to do automatically? If so I think you are putting a band aid on a bullet hole.

Comment: That was my first question as well, but this is also for maintenance situations as well. Also this application is required to follow our main application to whichever data center is primary at the time. So even if this app doesn't go down, if our main application switched data centers, this one is required to automatically switch as well  to minimize latency.

Comment: OK...the command you are looking for is [replSetReconfig](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetReconfig/). `rs.reconfig` is just a wrapper around this. To force the reconfig when there's no primary/majority, set `force : true`. Also check out the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/) on this. Be warned this makes me nervous :/

Comment: I'm getting this error when I do that.

`Command 'replSetReconfig' failed: replSetReconfig command must be sent to the current replica set primary. (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "replSetReconfig command must be sent to the current replica set primary." })`

Comment: Are you using the force option?

Comment: I am, from what I can tell from the documentation, it's being used correctly. I could be wrong though. 

    `var reconfigCommand = new CommandDocument{{"replSetReconfig", new BsonDocument{{"configuration", newConfig},{"force", true}}}};

    var response = database.RunCommand(reconfigCommand);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use rs.reconfig on the server.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/

If majority of the servers are down then you will have to specify force option during reconfig.

```
rs.reconfig(cfg,{force:true});
```

Where cfg is you new configuration which has your currently live host.

Note: this has to be executed from mongo shell.

Comment: Right, I realize I can do it manually. I need this to executed from the web service. Another application is going to call a web service method that will execute a reconfig so preform a switch-over. Data center 2 gets notified when data center 1 goes offline. Then that notification will trigger an event that moves the mongo primary to data center 2.